# The interactive plot in plotly didn't appear in the rendered shinyApp page

Tags: r, plotly, reactive, shinyapps

I have an issue with making interactive plot in shinyApp. The data I have used is comprised 6 variables and 512 observations: Year, month, channel , viewCount , commentCount , likeCount. This is my reproducible code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(thematic)
library(ragg)
library(showtext)


df <- read.csv(file_path)
thematic_shiny(font = "Pacifico")

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Select theme
  shinythemes::themeSelector(),
  
  tags$style(HTML("
    body {
      font-family: 'Pacifico', 15; /*Set up fonts for the page
  ")),
  
  # Fix widgets
  tags$head(
    tags$script(HTML('
       $(document).ready(function() {
        // Get the position of the sidebar
        var sidebarPosition = $(".sidebar").offset().top;

        // Function to fix or unfix the sidebar based on scrolling
        function fixSidebar() {
          var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

          if (scrollTop > sidebarPosition) {
            $(".sidebar").addClass("fixed-sidebar");
          } else {
            $(".sidebar").removeClass("fixed-sidebar");
          }
        }

        // Attach the function to the scroll event
        $(window).scroll(fixSidebar);

        // Call the function once to set the initial state
        fixSidebar();
      });
    '))
  ),
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Youtube Data science Channels Analytics"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderTextInput(
        inputId = "year_slider",
        label = "Select Year",
        choices = as.character(2017:2024),
        selected = "2023",
        width = "300px"
      )
    )
  ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel('View Count', plotOutput('view_plot')),
        tabPanel('Comment Count', plotOutput('comment_plot')),
        tabPanel('Like Count', plotOutput('like_plot'))
    )
  )
)

server<-function(input, output) {
  
  
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)
  library(lubridate)
  
  df$channel <- as.factor(df$channel)
  
  #Filtering
  channel_pipeline <- reactive({
    
    df %>% 
      group_by(channel, Year) %>%
      summarize(
        viewCount = mean(viewCount), 
        commentCount = mean(commentCount), 
        likeCount = mean(likeCount)) %>% 
      arrange(Year, .by_group = T) %>% 
      filter(as.numeric(Year) %in% as.numeric(input$year_slider)) %>%
      as.data.frame()
  })
  
  # View Plot
  library(RColorBrewer)
  # Define color scale
  color_scale <- brewer.pal(length(unique(df$channel)), "Spectral")
  
  
  output$view_plot <- renderPlotly({
    channel_data <- channel_pipeline()
    print(head(isolate(channel_data())))   # Add this line for debugging
    
    plot_ly(data = channel_pipeline(), x = ~as.character(channel_pipeline()$channel), y = ~viewCount*1e-3, type = 'bar', color = ~as.character(channel_pipeline()$channel),
            colors = color_scale(length(unique(df$channel))))
    
    layout(xaxis = list(title = ''), yaxis = list(title = expresiom(10^3)))
    
    # Second approach to build an interactive plot
    # p1 <- ggplot(data = channel_pipeline(), aes(x = channel, y = viewCount*1e-3, fill = channel)) +
    #   geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.7, alpha = .8) +
    #   scale_fill_manual(values = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n = length(unique(df$channel)), name = 'Spectral')) +
    #   labs(title = "Videos performance by channels", x = "Channel") +
    #   scale_y_continuous(expression(10^3)) +
    #   theme_minimal() +
    #   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
    #         axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0.5),
    #         axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0)) +
    #   scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) {
    #     if (is.Date(x[1])) {
    #       format(x, "%Y")
    #     } else {
    #       x
    #     }
    #   })
    
    # ggplotly(p1)
    # p1
  })
  
  # Comments plot
  output$comment_plot <- renderPlotly({
    
    channel_data <- channel_pipeline()
    
    print(head(isolate(channel_data())))
    
    plotly(data = channel_data, x =~as.charater(channel_data()$channel), y =~commentCount*1e-3, color = as.character(channel_data()$channel), type = 'bar',
           colors = color_scale(length(unique(df$channel))))
    
    layout(xaxis = list(title = ''), yaxis = list(title = expresiom(10^3)))
    
    # Second approach to build an interactive plot
    # p2 <- ggplot(data = channel_pipeline(), aes(x = channel, y = commentCount*1e-3, fill = channel)) +
    #   geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.7, alpha =.8) +
    #   scale_fill_manual(values = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n = length(unique(df$channel)), name = 'Spectral')) +
    #   labs(title = "Videos performance by channels",
    #        x = "Channel"
    #   ) +
    #   scale_y_continuous(expression(10^3)) +
    #   theme_minimal() +
    #   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
    #         axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0.5),
    #         axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0)) +
    #   scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) {
    #     if (is.Date(x[1])) {
    #       format(x, "%Y")
    #     } else {
    #       x
    #     }
    #   })
    # 
    # # ggplotly(p2)
    # p2
  })
  
  # Likes plot
  output$like_plot <- renderPlotly({
    
    channel_data <- channel_pipeline()
    
    print(head(isolate(channel_data())))
    
    plotly(data = channel_data, x =~as.charater(channel_data()$channel), y =~likeCount*1e-3, color = as.character(channel_data()$channel), type = 'bar',
           colors = color_scale(length(unique(df$channel))))
    
    layout(xaxis = list(title = ''), yaxis = list(title = expresiom(10^3)))
    
    # Second approach to build an interactive plot
    # p3 <- ggplot(data = channel_pipeline(), aes(x = channel, y = likeCount*1e-3, fill = channel)) +
    #   geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.7, alpha =.8) +
    #   scale_fill_manual(values = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n = length(unique(df$channel)), name = 'Spectral')) +
    #   labs(title = "Videos performance by channels",
    #        x = "Channel"
    #   ) +
    #   scale_y_continuous(expression(10^3)) +
    #   theme_minimal() +
    #   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
    #         axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0.5),
    #         axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0)) +
    #   scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) {
    #     if (is.Date(x[1])) {
    #       format(x, "%Y")
    #     } else {
    #       x
    #     }
    #   })
    # ggplotly(p3)
    # p3
  }  
  )
  
})
  
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have tried to use ggplotly to convert ggplots into interactive charts, but I get only simple static plots.
If you will have some time to review my issue to build a shinyApp with interactive plots I will be very grateful.

Comment: Try with `plotlyOutput` instead of `plotOutput`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using plotly in Shiny, make sure to use `plotlyOutput()` in your UI and not just `plotOutput()` in order for your interactive graph to be displayed. Here is an adjustment to the `mainPanel()` of your app:

```
mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel('View Count', plotlyOutput('view_plot')),
        tabPanel('Comment Count', plotlyOutput('comment_plot')),
        tabPanel('Like Count', plotlyOutput('like_plot'))
    )
  )
)
```

I hope it helps!